# pipe delimited text to xml conversion

Tags: perl, shell

I have a text file which I need to convert into xml. The very first line of the text contains heading which would go as a xml tags.Each of other lines will go as value of xml tags. Example input (`ABC.txt`):

```
ID|Name|Subject|Marks
12|Sam|PHY,MATH|60
13|Gan|CHY|70
25|Rane|PHY|78
```

This would be converted into `Output.xml`:

```
<Record>
  <ID>12</ID>
  <Name>Sam</Name>
  <Subject>PHY,MATH</Subject>
  <Marks>60</Marks>
</Record>
<Record>
  <ID>13</ID>
  <Name>Gan</Name>
  <Subject>CHY</Subject>
  <Marks>70</Marks>
</Record>
<Record>
  <ID>25</ID>
  <Name>Rane</Name>
  <Subject>PHY</Subject>
  <Marks>78</Marks>
</Record>
```

Is there any module exists to achieve the same like XML::CSV?

Thanks,

Man

Answer (score 4):

Read ABC.txt in [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/Text-CSV-1.21/lib/Text/CSV.pm) (set appropriate separator), turn it to hasref and write out with [`XML::Simple`](http://search.cpan.org/~grantm/XML-Simple-2.18/lib/XML/Simple.pm)

Answer (score 2):

[XML::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/~grantm/XML-Simple-2.18/lib/XML/Simple.pm) would work well here; create a hashmap of your data, feed it into XML::Simple, then call XMLout. The only real work you have to do is massaging your lines into the hashmap... split on '|' to get the fields and you're most of the way there.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a temp file that holds the CSV content and feed that one to `XML::CSV`:

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

open my $fh, '<', "abc.txt" or die "can't open input";
my @in_content = <$fh>;
close $fh;

my @tmp;
open my $out, '>', "temp.txt" or die "can't open tempfile";
foreach my $in(@in_content){
  print {$out} join(';', split(/\|/,$in));
}

close $out;

# now, you can use temp.txt as input for XML::CSV
```